# What is the correct way to perform one sample paired wilcoxon test in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Let's say I have a dataframe called `df`, with two variables - `weight_0` and `weight_1`. `weight_0` describes the weight of participants before intervention, and `weight_1` describes the weight of the same participants after intervention. Now, I want to know if the entire cohort demonstrated weight loss during the trial, so I would use the paired Wilcoxon test to compute P-value. I used to be a Python user, so I did it with the pingouin package

```
import pingouin as pg
pg.wilcoxon(x=df["weight_0"], y=df["weight_1"])
```

The output would be

```
|W-val|alternative|p-val|RBC|CLES|
|Wilcoxon|11459.5|two-sided|0.004|0.214|0.535|
```

The same would happen if I would use the famous scipy

```
import scipy.stats as stats
stats.wilcoxon(x=df["weight_0"], y=df["weight_1"])
WilcoxonResult(statistic=11459.5, pvalue=0.003966344096710916)
```

I started using R on the same dataset, and to my suprise I got a different P value

```
wilcox.test(x = df$weight_0, y = df$weight_1, paired = T)
Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data: df$weight_0 and df$weight_1
V = 13112, p-value = 0.02105
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

However, If I calculte a variable which is the difference in weight,

```
weight_del = weight_1 - weight_0
```

I get a result which is similar to Python:

```
wilcox.test(df$weight_del, mu = 0)
Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
```

```
data: df$weight_del
V = 11460, p-value = 0.003972
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

I have seen numerous posts online regarding different results between R and Python while performing the Wilcoxon test. However, I don't understand why I get similar results if I'm using the 'del' variable and what is happening under the hood. In addition, I don't have a small N which is described in some posts as the source of difference (N ~ 200).

Comment: You would expect `pingouin` and `scipy` to match because this is the [`pingoun.wilcoxon`](https://github.com/raphaelvallat/pingouin/blob/3cfb64966032499693371f624819a5e4fe5a4fcc/src/pingouin/nonparametric.py#L458) source code: `wval, pval = scipy.stats.wilcoxon(x=x, y=y, alternative=alternative, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

An important difference between `scipy.stats.wilcoxon` is that the "continuity correction" is off by default (`correction=False`). `wilcox.test` on the other hand performes it by default (`correct=TRUE`).
The correction should only influence the pvalue and not the mean difference. You could try to rerun the `scipy.stats.wilcoxon` and set `correction=True` and see if the results are the same.